# Many-to-many relationships on a specific column for Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship, junction-table

I have 3 tables: Book, Section and Content. I want to add many-to-many relation between Section and Content. Section and Content tables have a PageNo column. A Page may have many contents and many Sections. In Brief:

```
Book 1----* Section (on BookId)
Book 1----* Content (on BookId)
Section *-----* Content (on PageNo)
```

The PageNo is not unique for both Section and Content tables. So I can't add foreign key for PageNo in Sql Server.

I tried to create a junction table like this:

```
SectionContent: [SectionId, ContentId]
```

And I added FKs for this junction table. So entity framework could understand the junction table and it set up many-to-many relationship on SectionId and ContentId. But everytime when I need to insert one of Section or Content Table, I have to insert to SectionContent junction table, too. So first I have to check if there is a same record already in the junction table. Also there are a lot of insert operations in the project. I have to search for all insert operations and I have to add extra query to insert into the junction table.

Also I need get the sections and contents in a page. This is extra effort for me.

I can remove the relationship between Section and Content tables. And I can use extra join queries on PageNo column. But I want to use entity. I want to get Contents in entity way like Section.Contents and I want to get Sections in the same way like Content.Sections.

So can I add many-to-many association between Section and Content on PageNo column without SQL Server's FKs?

Edit: Also If I use the junction table above, I must execute an sql query like this, do I?

```
INSERT INTO SectionContent
SELECT * FROM 
(
    SELECT Section.id AS SectionId, Content.id AS ContentId
    FROM Section
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Content
        ON Section.PageNo = Content.PageNo AND 
           Section.BookId = Content.BookId 

    UNION

    SELECT Section.id AS SectionId, Content.id AS ContentId
    FROM Section
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN Content
        ON Section.PageNo = Content.PageNo AND 
           Section.BookId = Content.BookId 
) AS T
WHERE SectionId is not NULL AND ContentID is not NULL
GROUP BY T.SectionId, T.ContentId
```

Comment: I have a workaround. But it isn't still practical solution. I've created a Page table that has id, BookId, PageNo columns. And I removed PageNo columns from Section and Content tables. Also I added a new column named PageId that related to id column of the Page table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by using EF Code First. I've implemented all tables as a class and EF handled all many-to-many relationships.